# How do I kill a specific java file after one hour, without knowing it's specific PID?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Currently my batch file will launch 20 jars with different arguments, after an hour, a taskkill command kills all java, the batch file will now launch 20 different jars.

My problem is, max cpu usage on startup, and potentially wasted cpu later. I could start the jar files at different times, but then they won't run for equal amounts of time. Takes up to 5 minutes for the cpu usage to half.

I need to launch a jar file, then kill it in an hour, without touching the other 19 jar files, and without knowing the PID.

I have been browsing the web and I see some stuff about, making it a background process, then getting the PID that way, can someone help me out with that?

This is what it looks like now

```
java -jar file.jar -a first
timeout 3
java -jar file.jar -a second
timeout 3
java -jar file.jar -a third
timeout 3
```

Comment: Why can't you know the PID?

Comment: File? Do you mean *process*?

Comment: You can use wmic to check which process was started an hour ago.

Answer (score 1):

Use jps.exe utility (which is part of standard JDK) to learn the PID of the just started Java process. Then use taskkill /pid to kill this one process.

Comment: can you give me an example of a script that does this automatically? or are you telling me to manually do taskkill?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to have some fun here :)

If you don't have ownership of the jars you might try something like:

```
public class KillTask extends TimerTask {

    private Process process;

    public KillTask(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Prepare to die!
        process.destroy();
    }
}

public class KillDriver {

    public KillDriver(String command) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            new Timer().schedule(new KillTask(process), 60 * 60 * 1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : args)
            new KillDriver(s);
    }
}
```

This example assumes multiple jars will be started but you can alter that for a single or possibly pass in the delay as an argument to add some flexibility.

Comment: @WebMaster, that's not obvious? Yes, it's Java. Are you not able to write a little code to accomplish your goals :). BTW, I removed the first part where you might be willing to alter the jars; I see you can't/won't.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are giving the Jars their own process names ("first", "second", "third"), so I assume you could use a VBscript like this that does not require the PID to kill it.

```
ProcessName = "FIRST"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy,(Debug)}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
  For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    If InStr(UCase(objProcess.Name), ProcessName) Then
      WScript.Echo "Killing " & objProcess.Name
      objProcess.Terminate()
    End If
  Next
```